# ngx-translate - check if translation file is available

Tags: javascript, angular

How do I check if a translation file is available for the result you get from `navigator.language` using ngx-translate?

I want to do something like:

```
if( checkLanguageAvailable (navigator.language)) {
 this.translate.use( navigator.language );
} else {
 this.translate.use( 'en' ); //Default fall back
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the getLangs() method of ngx-translate to get a list of available languages:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class MyController {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

  checkLanguageAvailable(lang: string): boolean {
    return this.translate.getLangs().includes(lang);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u can check file exist before use it (make http.get, but this will load file...)

or use **missingTranslationHandler**, example:
**app.module.ts**

```
import ...

export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate: true,
      missingTranslationHandler: [{provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: TranslateHandler}]
    }),
    SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot()
  ],
...
```

**TranslateHandler**

```
import {MissingTranslationHandler, MissingTranslationHandlerParams} from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class TranslateHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
  private response: String;
  handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {   
    return 'some translated text'; // here u can return translation 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution:

```
this.translate.use(navigator.language.split(/-|_/)[0]).toPromise().catch(() => {
  this.translate.use('en');
});
```